# Locally installing dotnet tool uses old command name

Tags: c#, .net-core, csproj, dotnet-tool

I've followed the tutorials to [create a dotnet tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/global-tools-how-to-create) and [install it locally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/local-tools-how-to-use). After I was satisfied, I tried changing the name of the command from `botsay` to `something-else`. Unfortunately it always installs with the command name `botsay`. Even if I run `dotnet tool uninstall`, delete the project, and start over, it keeps using the name from the tutorial. The only way I can change it is by changing the project name to something else. Why does it use the old command name and how can I change it?

The directory structure is:

```
sources
--My.Project.Name
----nupkg
------My.Project.Name.1.0.0.nupkg
--.config
----dotnet-tools.json
```

My csproj is:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>

        <PackAsTool>true</PackAsTool>
        <ToolCommandName>something-else</ToolCommandName>
        <PackageOutputPath>./nupkg</PackageOutputPath>
    </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

And the dotnet-tools.json is:

```
{
  "version": 1,
  "isRoot": true,
  "tools": {
    "my-project-name": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "commands": [
        "botsay" <--- I want this to be "something-else"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, found the answer. The package was being installed from a cache. I had tried supplying the `--no-cache` argument to `dotnet tool install`, but it didn't make a difference. The solution is:

1. run `nuget locals all -List`
2. find the cached package in one of these locations
3. delete it